# Multilingual search in SharePoint 2013

Tags: search, search-results, multilingual

Our SP2013 farm (standard edition on-premise) contains both English and Chinese documents. In search center users have to switch the language preference to get the full results. It is because some results only show up in Chinese preference while some only in English.

Can we change the search result page or any settings so that all results will show up regardless the client language preference?

Comment: @ Mark L Did you find the Solution..?

Comment: @TARUN no there is no solution... maybe change to Google search